# Newlines inside CSV data break Text::CSV reading

Tags: perl

I have some sample data (from a *Google Sheets* spreadsheet);

```
Title,Website URL,Description,Contact Number,Address 1,Address 2,City,State ,Province,Country,Facebook,Twitter,Full Category Name
Sample title,http://www.test.com,"A short description. Press Ctrl+Enter to create a new line

Like this",44 (0)1430 123 123,Some address line,Line 2,The city,The state,Some province,UK,facebook.com/test,twitter.com/test,Full Category/Path/To/Category or ID
```

I then have this simple script:

```
use Text::CSV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    sep_char => ','
   });
   $csv->column_names("title","url","description","contact_number","address1","address2","city","state","province","country","facebook","twitter","category_name");

my $file = './tmp/$USER->{Username}.csv';

open (WRITEIT, ">:encoding(utf8)", $file) or die "cant write $file: $!";
    print WRITEIT join("\n", @data). "\n";
close (WRITEIT) or die "cant write $file: $!";

open my $io, "<:encoding(utf8)", $file or die "$file: $!";

use Data::Dumper;

my $i = 0;
while (my $row = $csv->getline_hr($io)) {

    $i++;

    print Dumper($row);

}
```

The problem with this, is that I get the following output:

```
$VAR1 = 'Sample title,http://www.test.com,"A short description. Press Ctrl+Enter to create a new line
';
$VAR2 = '
';
$VAR3 = 'Like this",44 (0)1430 123 123,Some address line,Line 2,The city,The state,Some province,UK,facebook.com/test,twitter.com/test,Full Category/Path/To/Category or ID';
```

It's taking the \n in the description as a newline. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#Embedded-newlines:

> **Important Note:** The default behavior is to accept only ASCII characters in the range from `0x20` (space) to `0x7E` (tilde). This means that the fields can not contain newlines. If your data contains newlines embedded in fields, or characters above `0x7E` (tilde), or binary data, you ***must*** set `binary => 1` in the call to `new`. To cover the widest range of parsing options, you will always want to set binary.

Comment: Oh you legend! Works like a charm now :)